# Which pattern to use to avoid code duplication with object value transformer

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract-class, code-duplication

I want to get rid of the following code duplication within the `MyFacadeBean`. Consider the following situation:

```
public class FacadeBean implements Facade {

    @EJB
    private CrudService crudService;

    @Inject
    private FirstAssembler firstAssembler;
    @Inject
    private SecondAssembler secondAssembler;
    @Inject
    private ThirdAssembler thridAssembler;
    @Inject
    private FourthAssembler fourthAssembler;

    @Override
    public void save(FirstValue value) {
        FirstEntity entity = this.firstAssembler.transformToEntity(value);
        this.crudService.persist(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(SecondValue value) {
        SecondEntity entity = this.secondAssembler.transformToEntity(value);
        this.crudService.persist(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(ThirdValue value) {
        ThirdEntity entity = this.thirdAssembler.transformToEntity(value);
        this.crudService.persist(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(FourthValue value) {
        FourthEntity entity = this.fourthAssembler.transformToEntity(value);
        this.crudService.persist(entity);
    }

}

public interface MyFacade {

    void save(FirstValue value);

    void save(SecondValue value);

}
```

With the `CrudService`:

```
public interface CrudService {

    void persist(Object entity);

}

@Stateless
@Local(CrudService.class)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
public class CrudServiceBean implements CrudService {

    public static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "my_persistence_unit";

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME)
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void persist(Object entity) {
        this.entityManager.persist(entity);
    }

}
```

With the following assemblers:

```
public class FirstAssembler extends AbstractAssembler<FirstEntity> {

    public FirstEntity transformToEntity(FirstValue value) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        FirstEntity entity = new FirstEntity();
        transformAbstractValueToAbstractObject(value, entity);
        entity.setFixedRate(value.getFixedRate());
        entity.setStartDate(value.getStartDate());
        return entity;
    }

}

public class SecondAssembler extends AbstractAssembler<SecondEntity> {

    public SecondEntity transformToEntity(SecondValue value) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        SecondEntity entity = new SecondEntity();
        transformAbstractValueToAbstractObject(value, entity);
        entity.setTransactionType(value.getTransactionType());
        entity.setValueDate(value.getValueDate());
        return entity;
    }

}

public abstract class AbstractAssembler<T extends AbstractEntity> {

    protected void transformAbstractValueToAbstractObject(AbstractValue value, T object) {
        object.setUniqueId(value.getUniqueId());
        object.setNominalAmountValue(value.getNominalAmountValue());
    }

}
```

With the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class FirstEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "START_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date startDate;
    @Column(name = "FIXED_RATE")
    @Digits(integer = 1, fraction = 10)
    private BigDecimal fixedRate;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public BigDecimal getFixedRate() {
        return fixedRate;
    }

    public void setFixedRate(BigDecimal fixedRate) {
        this.fixedRate = fixedRate;
    }

}


@Entity
public class SecondEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "VALUE_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date valueDate;
    @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_TYPE")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TransactionType transactionType;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getValueDate() {
        return valueDate;
    }

    public void setValueDate(Date valueDate) {
        this.valueDate = valueDate;
    }

    public TransactionType getTransactionType() {
        return transactionType;
    }

    public void setTransactionType(TransactionType transactionType) {
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
    }

}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_NOM_AMOUNT_VALUE")
    @Digits(integer = 18, fraction = 5)
    @Min(0)
    private BigDecimal nominalAmountValue;

    public BigDecimal getNominalAmountValue() {
        return nominalAmountValue;
    }

    public void setNominalAmountValue(BigDecimal nominalAmountValue) {
        this.nominalAmountValue = nominalAmountValue;
    }

}
```

I tried the following approach:

```
public class FacadeBean implements Facade {
    @Inject
    private Assembler assembler;

    @Inject
    private AssemblerFactory assemblerFactory;

    @Override
    public <T extends AbstractValue> void save(T value) {
        Assembler assembler = assemblerFactory.createAssembler(value);
        AbstractEntity entity = assembler.transformToEntity(value);
        this.crudService.persist(entity);
    }
}
```

Problems are the AssemblerFactoryImpl and the AssemblerImpl in which I have to do instanceOf checks and castings...

Another idea would be to let the value know which transformer to use (or how to transform). But I want the value to be "dumb".

@Glenn Lane

```
public AbstractValue save(AbstractValue value) {
    AbstractAssembler<AbstractValue, AbstractEntity> assembler = new FirstAssembler();
    AbstractEntity entity = assembler.transformToEntity(value);
    AbstractValue result = assembler.transformToValue(entity);
    return result;
}
```

does not work, because of

Type mismatch: cannot convert from FirstAssembler to AbstractAssembler

Comment: Chris311, in `FacadeBean` are there missing lines `@Inject private SecondAssembler secondAssembler;` and `@Inject private ThirdAssembler thirdAssembler;`?

Comment: Have a look around the design pattern visitor to avoid instanceOf checks and castings

Comment: See my second answer (visitor pattern) to see how to have one save method for `AbstractValue` without `instanceof`, class comparisons (i.e. class-to-factory map), casting, or any other clumsiness.

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting this as a separate answer, since I don't really think there's anything wrong with having a save method for every AbstractValue type.

First we'll establish your base value class for this example.  I'm using an interface just so we don't muddy the waters.  Your `AbstractValue` interface:

```
public interface AbstractValue
{
    int getUniqueId();
    double getNominalValue();
    <T> T accept(AbstractValueVisitor<T> visitor);
}
```

And the "visitor interface":

```
public interface AbstractValueVisitor<T>
{
    T visit(FirstValue value);
    T visit(SecondValue value);
    T visit(ThirdValue value);
    T visit(FourthValue value);
}
```

I know you don't want intelligence baked into `AbstractValue`, but we are going to add *one* specification... that all concrete implementations of `AbstractValue` (all four) implement the `accept` method exactly this way:

```
@Override
public <T> T accept(AbstractValueVisitor<T> visitor)
{
    return visitor.visit(this);
}
```

So that method is implemented *four* times: in all four value classes, exactly the same way.  Because the visitor interface is aware of all concrete implementations, the appropriate method will be called for each particular value type.  All three of these parts put together is the "visitor pattern".

Now we'll make an entity factory.  Its job is to create the appropriate `AbstractEntity` when provided an `AbstractValue`:

```
public class AbstractEntityFactory
        implements AbstractValueVisitor<AbstractEntity>
{
    private static final AbstractEntityFactory INSTANCE;

    static
    {
        INSTANCE = new AbstractEntityFactory();
    }

    // Singleton pattern
    private AbstractEntityFactory()
    {
    }

    public static AbstractEntity create(AbstractValue value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        AbstractEntity e = value.accept(INSTANCE);
        e.setNominalValue(value.getNominalValue());
        e.setUniqueId(value.getUniqueId());
        return e;
    }


    @Override
    public AbstractEntity visit(FirstValue value)
    {
        FirstEntity entity = new FirstEntity();
        // Set all properties specific to FirstEntity
        entity.setFixedRate(value.getFixedRate());
        entity.setStartDate(value.getStartDate());
        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractEntity visit(SecondValue value)
    {
        SecondEntity entity = new SecondEntity();
        // Set all properties specific to SecondEntity
        entity.setTransactionType(value.getTransactionType());
        entity.setValueDate(value.getValueDate());
        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractEntity visit(ThirdValue value)
    {
        ThirdEntity entity = new ThirdEntity();
        // Set all properties specific to ThirdEntity
        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractEntity visit(FourthValue value)
    {
        FourthEntity entity = new FourthEntity();
        // Set all properties specific to FourthEntity
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Now your facade implementation takes an `AbstractValue`, and you got that one save method you're looking for:

```
public class FacadeBean implements Facade
{
    @EJB
    private CrudService crudService;

    @Override
    public void save(AbstractValue value)
    {
        AbstractEntity entity = AbstractEntityFactory.create(value);
        crudService.persist(entity);
    }
}
```

Because your `AbstractValue` now follows the visitor pattern, you can do all sorts of polymorphic behavior.  Such as:

```
public class AbstractValuePrinter implements AbstractValueVisitor<Void>
{
    private final Appendable out;

    public AbstractValuePrinter(Appendable out)
    {
        this.out = out;
    }

    private void print(String s)
    {
        try
        {
            out.append(s);
            out.append('\n');
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Void visit(FirstValue value)
    {
        print("I'm a FirstValue!");
        print("Being a FirstValue is groovy!");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Void visit(SecondValue value)
    {
        print("I'm a SecondValue!");
        print("Being a SecondValue is awesome!");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Void visit(ThirdValue value)
    {
        print("I'm a ThirdValue!");
        print("Meh.");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Void visit(FourthValue value)
    {
        print("I'm a ThirdValue!");
        print("Derp.");
        return null;
    }
}
```

In this example, this visitor isn't returning anything... it's "doing" something, so we'll just set the return value as `Void`, since it's non-instantiatable.  Then you print the value simply:

```
// (value must not be null)
value.accept(new AbstractValuePrinter(System.out));
```

Finally, the coolest part of the visitor pattern (in my opinion): you add `FifthValue`.  You add the new method to your visitor interface:

```
T visit(FifthValue value);
```

And suddenly, **you can't compile**.  You *must* address the lack of this handling in two places: `AbstractEntityFactory` and `AbstractValuePrinter`.  Which is great, because you *should* consider it in those places.  Doing class comparisons (with either `instanceof` or rinde's solution of a class-to-factory map) is likely to "miss" the new value type, and now you have runtime bugs... especially if you're doing 100 different things with these value types.

Anyhoo, I didn't want to get into this, but there you go :)

Comment: There are still several things I personally don't like: 1. The value is not as "dumb" as before. 2. The code duplication now goes to the "AbstractEntityFactory", which does not adress the problem in the topic of this post. But still, I really like this solution and I gave you the reward.

Answer (score 2):

Use a generic method with a bound type parameter in order to spare yourself the repetition:

`public <T extends AbstractValue> T save(T value) {...}`

Within the method body, you'll be able to reference the argument `value` with all methods pertaining to `AbstractValue`.

**Notes**

- Since your `save` methods seem to be overrides in this example, you might need to change the design of the parent class or interface too.
- You could also use a generic class to start with (instead of a generic method in a non-necessarily generic class), depending on your use case.

Comment: And how do you know which assembler to use without an instanceOf check?

Comment: @Chris311 not really, as I don't have enough context to do so. But let me reformulate my previous comment: why don't you have a factory of `Assembler`s returning the right one, given a certain value? That way you could abstract the `Assemblers` under one interface so the `save` method is de-coupled from the exact `Assembler` type to use.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without having castings and instanceOf checks. I will edit my initial post to show you why.

Comment: Btw, if you need more context information, please tell me what you need to know. I faced this problem in different projects and i couldn't figure out the Best Practice here. I really think that there must be a good (generic) way to solve this.

Comment: The problem is that with design pattern/architecture questions in general, it's very hard to display a self-contained example both on the question and on the answer's side. If you want a better answer you're probably going to have to rework the code displayed question to have a self-contained context, e.g. what does what at this moment. However, you need to be synthetic enough not to bloat your question with pages of code (you might risk getting downvoted by passerbys otherwise...). Or, you can try [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: @Chris311 missed your last edit. Can you have a property of each instance of `AbstractValue` dictating the `Assembler` to use?

Comment: @Chris311 Since Mena mentioned it, closely read what is [on topic at codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if you even try to post there. As the question stand, it would likely be closed as off-topic for either hypothetical code or code not yet written.

Comment: @Mena I can design all of the used values and classes, so the answer is yes. What is your intention? Maybe you can just post an answer, which I can then review so that I might tell what does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think a problem in your code is that the generic type of `AbstractAssembler` is that of the output of the transform method, not the input. If you change it as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractAssembler<T extends AbstractValue> {
  protected void transformAbstractValueToAbstractObject(AbstractEntity entity, T value) {
    entity.setUniqueId(value.getUniqueId());
    entity.setNominalAmountValue(value.getNominalAmountValue());
  }

  public abstract AbstractEntity transformToEntity(T value);
}
```

Then you can change the `FacadeBean` to the following.

```
public class FacadeBean {  
  @EJB
  private CrudService crudService;

  final Map<Class<?>, AbstractAssembler<?>> knownAssemblers;

  FacadeBean() {
    knownAssemblers = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    knownAssemblers.put(FirstValue.class, new FirstAssembler());
    knownAssemblers.put(SecondValue.class, new SecondAssembler());
    // add more assemblers here
  }

  public <T extends AbstractValue> void save(T value, Class<T> type) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // safe cast
    final AbstractAssembler<T> assembler = 
      (AbstractAssembler<T>) knownAssemblers.get(type);

    final AbstractEntity entity = assembler.transformToEntity(value);
    this.crudService.persist(entity);
  }  
}
```

Notice that I changed the signature of the `save(..)` method such that we have the type of the object that needs to be saved. With this type we can simply lookup the right assembler that should be used. And because the assembler is now generic on its input type, we can do a safe cast (be careful to keep your map consistent).

This implementation avoids duplication of code as you only need one save method. The use of the `instanceof` operator is prevented by changing the generic type of `AbstractAssembler` and storing all assemblers in a map.

The assemblers can look like this:

```
public class FirstAssembler extends AbstractAssembler<FirstValue> {
  @Override
  public FirstEntity transformToEntity(FirstValue value) {
    final FirstEntity entity = new FirstEntity();
    // do transformational stuff
    super.transformAbstractValueToAbstractObject(entity, value);
    entity.setFixedRate(value.getFixedRate());
    entity.setStartDate(value.getStartDate());
    return entity;
  }
}   

public class SecondAssembler extends AbstractAssembler<SecondValue> {
  @Override
  public SecondEntity transformToEntity(SecondValue value) {
    final SecondEntity entity = new SecondEntity();
    // do transformational stuff
    super.transformAbstractValueToAbstractObject(entity, value);
    return entity;
  }
}
```

**Note**: I'm not familiar with Java beans so you probably have to adapt the code a little if you want to use the `@Inject`ed assemblers instead of calling the constructors directly.

Comment: I already found a solution with castings ans instanceOf-checks. I asked for one without such stuff.

Comment: This solution is without `instanceof`, the casting is a necessary evil unless you throw all type safety overboard (i.e. make everything `Object`). Besides, I think it is much more extensible and flexible compared to the other suggestions.

Comment: So you think that there is no solution without using instanceOf and castings? I thought that's exactly what generics where invented for...

Comment: The casting here is necessary due to a limitation of Java, it is not possible to express that the types of the key and value in the `knownAssemblers` map correspond, if it were possible you wouldn't need the cast..

Answer (score 0):

You're getting close to gold-plating here, but there is a bit of reduction you can do, specifically the `null`-check and calling the common field-setting method from each extension.

```
public abstract class AbstractAssembler<V extends AbstractValue, E extends AbstractEntity>
{
    public final E transformToEntity(V value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        E entity = createEntity(value);
        entity.setUniqueId(value.getUniqueId());
        entity.setNominalAmountValue(value.getNominalAmountValue());
        return entity;
    }

    /**
     * @return
     * Appropriate entity object, with the fields not common to all AbstractEntity
     * already set
     */
    protected abstract E createEntity(V value);
}
```

And then the extended assembler:

```
public class FirstAssembler extends AbstractAssembler<FirstValue, FirstEntity>
{
    @Override
    protected FirstEntity createEntity(FirstValue value)
    {
        FirstEntity entity = new FirstEntity();
        entity.setFixedRate(value.getFixedRate());
        entity.setStartDate(value.getStartDate());
        return entity;
    }
}
```

If you *really* want a single factory class to handle all your values/entities, I would look into the visitor pattern, enhanced with a generic type parameter on the visitor interface (and the entity/value accept methods return a type based on the visiting interface).  I won't show an example here simply because I don't think it's warranted in your case.

Comment: The interesting thing is how you implement the factory or anything that does this job. How do call the save methods, without having them 4 times?

Comment: @Chris311 Then you're insisting that `AbstractValue` has polymorphic behavior (conditional behavior dependent on extended class).  While you want polymorphic behavior, you also don't want to put intelligence into your AbstractValue class (which I think is very smart).  This means you'll want to use the "Visitor Pattern".  I'll post another answer to address this, since it's a little hard to explain (but awesome once you know it).

Answer (score -1):

You can have one save method from the point of view of the classes that save those values, but you still have to implement three individual save methods.

Implement a class with all three save methods. For example:

```
public class ValuePersister {
    @Inject
    private Assembler1 assembler1;
    @Inject
    private Assembler2 assembler2;
    @Inject
    private Assembler3 assembler3;

    public Value1 save(Value1 value1, CrudService crudService) {
        Entity1 entity1 = assembler1.transformToObject(value1);
        crudService.persist(entity1);
        return assembler1.transformToValue(entity1);
    }

    public Value2 save(Value2 value2, CrudService crudService) {
        Entity2 entity2 = assembler2.transformToObject(value2);
        crudService.persist(entity2);
        return assembler2.transformToValue(entity2);
    }

    public Value3 save(Value3 value3, CrudService crudService) {
        Entity3 entity3 = assembler3.transformToObject(value3);
        crudService.persist(entity3);
        return assembler3.transformToValue(entity3);
    }
}
```

Add an abstract method to AbstractValue:

```
public abstract AbstractValue save(ValuePersister valuePersister, CrudService crudService);
```

Implement that method in each class that extends AbstractValue:

```
@Override
public AbstractValue save(ValuePersister valuePersister, CrudService crudService) {
    return valuePersister.save(this, crudService);
}
```

Inject ValuePersister and implement your original generic save method:

```
@Inject
private ValuePersister valuePersister;

@Override
public AbstractValue save(AbstractValue value) {
    return value.save(valuePersister, crudService)
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is an improvement. It seems like the duplication get's just shifted somewhere else.I still think that those 3 save methods are duplication one could eliminate.